# Is my construction almost-surely a conditional Poisson random variable?

Tags: poisson-distribution, almost-everywhere

Suppose a continuous random variable $$L \sim F_{L}$$ where $$Pr[L = 0] = 0$$ even though $$L = 0$$ exists for some countable subset of the outcome space.

I am considering the existence of a variable

$$C \sim \text{Poisson}(L)$$

which would not be defined if $L=0$.

We could just condition that $L\neq 0$: $$C\mid L\neq0 \sim \text{Poisson}(L\mid L\neq0).$$

But in practice this doesn't make a lick of difference. Metropolis-Hastings sampling from $$\text{Poisson}(L)$$ works just fine for various choices of $F_L$ due to the almost-never occurrence of $L=0$.

Should I say that $C$ is almost-surely a random variable which follows a conditional Poisson distribution?

Comment: The main question is what is $P[L<0]$? If $L=0$ you can just define a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda=0$ as a random variable that is almost surely 0. Or, if you don't like that, assuming $P[L\leq 0]=0$ then you can define $$\tilde{L}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} L & \mbox{if $L>0$} \\ 1 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ and then $\tilde{L}$ is surely positive and has the same distribution as $L$.  Then make $C \sim Poisson(\tilde{L})$.

Comment: @Michael Ah yes, makes sense. I forget to impose a non-negativity constraint.